# React: iterating through javascript object key values

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

How do I put my props object into an array and iterate through it?

I have a bootstrap navigation bar that has dropdowns.  My code scans the javascript object and if the key `dropdown` is found, it will create a dropdown menu from the data in the javascript object from the `dropdown` section.

**My Javascript Object:**

```
var linksNav = {
    items: [
        {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "Events",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_self"
        },
        {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "Groups",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_self",
            "dropdown": 
                {
            "dropItems":
                    [
                        { 
                        "left": "1st left", 
                        "left-option": ["1","2"] 
                        },
                        { 
                        "left": "2nd left", 
                        "left-option": ["1","2"] 
                        },
                        { 
                        "left": "3rd left", 
                        "left-option": ["1","2"] 
                        },
                    ]
                }
        },
        {
            "type": "heading",
            "title": "Capabilities",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_self"
        },
    ]
}
```

This is my `LinksNav` class which creates the navigation bar by going through the javascript object.  If a `dropdown` item is detected in my javascript object, it will pass it to my `Navsub` component:

**LinksNav:**

```
var LinksNav = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

    let navDrop;        
    if (this.props.isDropdown) {
      navDrop = (
        <ul className="dropdown-menu fade">
        <div>{this.props.isDropdown.dropItems[0].left}></div>
         <Navsub isDropdown = {this.props.isDropdown}/>
        </ul>
      )
    }
        return (

            <li className={this.props.title + ' nav-items'}>

             <a href={this.props.href} target={this.props.target} className={this.state.color + ' dropdown-toggle'} onClick={this.onClick} data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{this.props.title}</a>

  {navDrop}       
            </li>

        );
    }
});
```

**Navsub:**
This is my `Navsub` class where I try to spit out the data from my dropdown list in my Javascript object if it can find it. :

```
   var Navsub = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        var itemsLeft= [];
       for (var j = 0; j < this.props.isDropdown.dropItems.length; j++) {
            itemsLeft.push(<Navsubrightitems key={j} type={this.props.isDropdown.dropItems[j].left} />);
        }
        return (
            <div className="group-dropdown-menu">
            <div className="dropdown-left-menu">

             {this.props.isDropdown.dropItems[0].left}
             {this.props.isDropdown.dropItems[1].left}
            </div>
             <div className="dropdown-right-menu">
            {itemsRight}

            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I can successfully grab the dropdown list from the json object throuhh props, as seen by my hardcoding:

```
{this.props.isDropdown.dropItems[0].left}
{this.props.isDropdown.dropItems[1].left}
```

, but I want to iterate through it so that I get the value of `left` under `dropItems` by putting it in an array and then spitting out those values.  I attempted to do so by iterating it through `this.props.isDropdown.dropItems.length`, but seems that's not valid as I get an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you want, Write it like this:

```
{
     this.props.isDropdown.dropItems && this.props.isDropdown.dropItems.map((item,i) => {
          return <Navsubrightitems key={i} type={item.left} />
     })
}
```

Comment: `.map` is for arrays, not objects, so this won't work unfortunately.

Comment: @clrux can you explain how that is an `object`, OP is checking the length `this.props.isDropdown.dropItems.length` and using like `this.props.isDropdown.dropItems[0].left` and `this.props.isDropdown.dropItems[1].left` check the ques again :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the props `dropDownItems` are not initially present and hence you need to check for and undefined value and then you can use map to iterate over these. You can do it as follows

```
var Navsub = React.createClass({
    render: function() {


        return (
            <div className="group-dropdown-menu">
            <div className="dropdown-left-menu">

             {this.props.isDropdown.dropItems[0].left}
             {this.props.isDropdown.dropItems[1].left}
            </div>
             <div className="dropdown-right-menu">
            {this.props.isDropdown.dropItems && this.props.isDropdown.dropItems.map((listItem, index) => {
                 return <Navsubrightitems key={index} type={listItem.left} />
               })}
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```